# USB driver failure in win 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

I have a problem with win7 USB driver and it no longer install new USB disks. I have no infcache.1 file anywhere on my windows directory and after checking the setupapi.dev.log, I faced this error msg triggered for any attempt for a USB recognition:

```
>>>  [Device Install (Hardware initiated) - USB\VID_0000&PID_0000\5&1dd99672&0&1]
>>>  Section start 2017/01/31 18:12:47.896
     ump: Creating Install Process: DrvInst.exe 18:12:47.904
     ndv: Retrieving device info...
     ndv: Setting device parameters...
     ndv: Searching just Driver Store...
     dvi: {Build Driver List} 18:12:48.074
     dvi:      Searching for hardware ID(s):
     dvi:           usb\unknown
     dvi:      Searching for compatible ID(s):
     dvi:           usb\unknown
     cpy:      Policy is set to make all digital signatures equal.
     dvi:      Enumerating INFs from path list 'C:\windows\INF'
!    inf:      Detected INFCACHE inconsistency
!    inf:      Attempting INFCACHE repair 18:14:48.141
!!!  inf:      Unable to fix INFCACHE - likely system corruption!
!!!  inf:      Error 32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
     ump:      Server install process exited with code 0x000005b4 18:17:48.077
<<<  Section end 2017/01/31 18:17:48.079
<<<  [Exit status: FAILURE(0x000005b4)]
```

maybe it will be interesting for you to know that when I run **pnputil -e** in cmd I get very same error:
"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Appreciate any solution, in advance.

Comment: 0x000005b4 = Timeout. stop Av suite before trying to update the driver

Comment: tnx, and i knew that but why a timeout? i know `Error 32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` responsible for the timeout

Comment: so stop your AV suite and try again

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the **INFCACHE.**1 file from **C:\Windows\System32\Driver Store** .
The file has become corrupted and inconsistent with the data found in Windows\Inf.

You need to alter permissions to delete it. Click on it, **Properties**, **Security** tab,  **Edit** and **Add**. Add the group **Administrators**. Now you can delete it.

Restart windows. When you connect a new device, the infcache will be re-created. Make sure not to connect the one that generated the problem. Let the infcache be created by connecting another device and then you can use the problem one too.

Comment: tnx but as I mentioned before, there is no INFCACHE file in my Windows directory (and its sub-dirs), so what should I do?

Comment: Don't just search for it from explorer; use a file manager to really see what's there. Alternately, uninstall USB root hub, USB mass storage while device is connected, remove the device, restart, let it re-detect, then either update usb root hub with windows or install latest chipset drivers.

Comment: I am sure that there is no such file because i have created a file with this name and some similar names (infcache.1, INFCACHE.1, infCache.**1, etc.) with no file exists error

Comment: It may be also a .2 or other number. Use a file manager to check the exact data there.